# Google places web Api direcly calling on the Angular 4 http Cors Issue

Tags: javascript, angular

I am consuming the Google Places autocomplete web service  directly in my angular 4 application using the http service , however I am not able get the response because of cors issue , cross domain resource sharing is not allowed.

i want to use the service directly without google javascript web API , how can i do that using this approach ? I need to deploy this in prod environment so i don't wanna use chrome  plugin.

My  code to invoke google place autocomplete api is :-

```
this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=geocode&key=YOUR_API_KEY').subscribe(response=>{
console.log(response.json());
});
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I have added the code snippet.

Comment: what is your question??

Comment: I am asking that response is not coming because this url api is throwing issue that cross origin resource sharing is not enabled how to bypass cors issue in this api?

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors